# Understanding Zorn's lemma for inductively ordered sets

Tags: set-theory

The statement goes: 
 Let the preordered set $(S,\preceq)$ be inductively
ordered. Then $S$ contains a minimal element, i.e. there is $\ \hat{s} \ $ ∈ S such that $\ s \preceq \hat{s} \ $ 
implies $\  \hat{s} \preceq s $. 
 Is this the same as saying that if we find an $s$ such that $\ s \preceq \hat{s} \ $  then $\ s = \hat{s} \ $? 

 Here the term inductively ordered is defined as a preordered set $(S,\preceq)$ for which every totally ordered subset has a lower bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether your definition of preorder implies antisymmetry, i.e. does $a \preceq b \wedge b \preceq a \implies a = b$ hold for your definition of a preorder?

Your conclusion holds if and only if the answer to the question above is affirmative.

Comment: The preorder $\preceq $ is defined as reflexive and transitive.  However, in the definition for inductive order, we consider totally ordered subsets of $ (S, \preceq )$. So, I could concluded that it is antisymmetric as well?

Comment: No, with this definition there are non-antisymmetric preorders. In fact (the reflexive closure of) the complete Graph $K_n$ with $n$ nodes is a preorder according to your definition and each of its elements is maximal.

Comment: Thanks. The example of $K_n $ really drove the point home.

Comment: You're most welcome ;-)